# How to force vim spellchecker to ignore lowercase/uppercase errors

Tags: spell-checking

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196399/exclude-capitalized-words-from-vim-spell-check) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561603/vim-spell-check-ignore-capitalized-words/7569127) how to force Vim spell checker to ignore words with capital letters from being check. But my case is quite opposite. I want to ignore words that in corrected form include capital letters.

So in sentence:

*europe was chozen best*

only word **chozen** is the wrong one.

How to achieve that?

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that Vim has a setting for this. One workaround is to create a new spellfile that contains everything in your current spell file(s) but with lowercase letters only:

1. Create a new buffer containing everything from the spell file(s) currently in use:

   ```
   :spelldump
   ```
2. Delete lines that don't contain any upper-case characters. This isn't strictly necessary, but there's no point keeping duplicate entries for lower-case words:

   ```
   :v/\u/d
   ```
3. Convert the entire file to lower-case, ignoring lines that contain the locations of the spell files:

   ```
   :v/^#/norm gu$
   ```
4. Save the file:

   ```
   :w ~/.vim/spell/lowercase.utf-8.add
   ```
5. Start using this file in addition to the standard files in Vim's `$VIMRUNTIME` directory. Note that Vim uses a default `'spellfile'` value internally if the setting is empty, so if you already have any existing spell files, you will need to ensure that they are included in this setting (which accepts a comma-delimited list):

   ```
   :set spellfile=~/.vim/spell/lowercase.utf-8.add
   ```

   Note that if you set this option in a running instance of Vim, it doesn't seem to take effect for spell-checking until you interact with it (by, e.g. using the `zg` command.)

The above doesn't affect the way that Vim detects lower-case words at the start of a sentence as spelled incorrectly. You can disable this with the `'spellcapcheck'` option:

```
:set spellcapcheck=
```